# case when then where

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a case statement with a where clause just for one of the "when" cases.

Basically:

```
Case when status='A' then sum(amount) where recorded_date=ongoing_date
when ...
else ...
```

The `where` only applies to the first case statement so I cant do `where case when ...`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
sum(case when status = 'A' and recorded_date = ongoing_date then amount else 0 end) as sum_a_sameday
```

Comment: would it matter if status comes from one table, recorded_date from another, and ongoing_date from a third?

Comment: @user8834780 . . . No it does not matter, if the joins are set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. Basically instead of using where, you can add all the required conditions under 'when' for each case:

```
CASE WHEN STATUS = 'A' AND recorded_date=ongoing_date THEN sum(amount)
WHEN STATUS = 'B' THEN ....
ELSE ...
```